# I can't connect my nodejs server to my mariadb raspberry pi

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mariadb

I'm trying to make a forum with a mariadb database on my raspberry pi (the nodejs server is on my computer and the database is on my raspberry)
I can't connect to my raspberry pi with a user...

i get this error :

```js
SqlError: (conn=-1, no: 45028, SQLState: HY000) retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10015ms
    at Object.module.exports.createError (C:\Users\Josselin Arnaud\Desktop\forum\node_modules\mariadb\lib\misc\errors.js:56:10)
    at Pool._requestTimeoutHandler (C:\Users\Josselin Arnaud\Desktop\forum\node_modules\mariadb\lib\pool.js:332:18)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {
  text: 'retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10015ms',
  sql: null,
  fatal: false,
  errno: 45028,
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  code: 'ER_GET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
}
```

and here is my code :

```js
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
     host: '192.168.0.45', 
     user:'root', 
     password: '*hello*',
     connectionLimit: 5
});
pool.getConnection()
    .then(conn => {
    
      conn.query("SELECT * FROM forum.utilisateur")
        .then((rows) => {
          console.log(rows); //[ {val: 1}, meta: ... ]
          //Table must have been created before 
          // " CREATE TABLE myTable (id int, val varchar(255)) "
          return conn.query("INSERT INTO forum.utilisateur value (?, ?)", [1, "mariadb", "mariadb", "mariadb", "mariadb"]);
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res); // { affectedRows: 1, insertId: 1, warningStatus: 0 }
          conn.end();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          //handle error
          console.log(err); 
          conn.end();
        })
        
    }).catch(err => {
      //not connected
      console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: You likely only allow local connections for `root` user.

Comment: @t.niese while that may well be the case, that's probably not the reason for a *timeout* I'm guessing more for a network related issue, for instance a firewall or no network connection between the two devices

Comment: Do you get another error before the timeout? The one at `//not connected`?

Comment: @t.niese there is an error handling for a failed `getConnection` . It's labelled with the comment `//not connected`

Comment: I'm also facing this issue.  I can connect to the same database from SQL Developer IDE, so I doubt it's a network or firewall issue.  I've tried with the same code as @jojubluch as well, so I'm comparing apples to apples.  I've tried with both a MariaDB and PostgreSQL database with the same result, suggesting the issue may be with Node.js.  I'm using Node version 20.10.0, and mariadb module version 3.2.2